# How can I deploy a .NET Maui app without using MSIX

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, maui, msix

**UPDATE:** I have been using the WiX Toolset to build installers for at least 10 years. Now, I am trying to add a Maui application to the installer, but...

1. MSIX only installs for the current user - I need it to be a machine-wide install.
2. MSIX installs to a hidden folder in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps... which I don't like. I want to install it into a folder I have control over.

My question is how can I build the Maui app and take the contents in the ...\bin... folder, run HEAT (a WiX utility) to create the WiX xxx.wxs file and build a WiX bundle with the other components in the application. It is not possible to deploy a MSIX file in a WiX bundle and even if it did, the issues I list above make this unfeasible.

How can I get all of the necessary files so that I can deploy a Maui app and not use MSIX?

@ToolmakerSteve - yes, I deploy .NET6/7 projects via WiX. The actual question here was how to publish a MAUI app in an unpackaged way. @jfversluis describes the process here:

[.NET MAUI Windows Unpackaged Apps](https://blog.verslu.is/maui/dotnet-maui-windows-unpackaged-apps/#:%7E:text=Enabling%20unpackaged%20distribution%20can%20be%20done%20in%202,and%20add%20the%20%3CWindowsPackageType%3ENone%3C%2FWindowsPackageType%3E%20node%20to%20a%20PropertyGroup.)

Comment: Can you publish a .Net 6 or 7 Windows App via WiX? I am not knowledgeable about current app publishing, but Maui on Windows is a Windows Desktop App. Perhaps that is a place to start, for a solution.

Comment: Yes, any windows app can be deployed using MSI authored by WiX.  You create a publish profile choosing your deployment options and then author the output of that into your installer.  I have tutorials on this over at GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this too. I am actually got to deploy it and run the Maui.exe file in my PC, however I got a purple screen. The key to deploy it is to use the heatdirectory in the bin and specific platform you are aiming for, (had only tested it in windows). Also I ran into light.exe problem and had to pack it not compressed. And you also has to enable the MAUI.exe to be functional.

The purple screen problem apparently has to do with WebView2, i am currently working on solving this. If anyone has any advice would be appreciated.

Here is my HeatDirectory configuration. The current dictionary of the Maui installer is in the same folder as the MauiApp

```
 <HeatDirectory OutputFile="ComponentsGenerated.wxs" DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER" ComponentGroupName="PublishedComponents" SuppressCom="true" Directory="..\MauiApp\bin\$(Configuration)\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-$(Platform)" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutoGenerateGuids="false" GenerateGuidsNow="true" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" RunAsSeparateProcess="true" PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath"/>
```

Here is what you have to add to Maui.csproj

None
true
true
WinExe

And to the launch.setting.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Windows Machine": {
      "commandName": "MsixPackage",
      "nativeDebugging": false
    }
  }
}
```